# super() method resolution in python

Tags: python, django

I am creating two custom widgets for django to use the chosen jQuery plugin, one for `ForeignKey` model fields and the other `ManyToManyField`. So, respectively, I override `forms.Select` and `forms.SelectMultiple`. I put the common functionality in a common parent class as:

```
class ChosenWidgetParent(object):
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': (
                'sub/staticfull/css/plugins/chosen/chosen.css',
            )
        }
        js = (
            'sub/staticfull/js/jquery-2.1.1.js',
            'sub/staticfull/js/plugins/chosen/chosen.jquery.js',
        )
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, **kwargs):
        attrs['chosen'] = 'chosen'
        rendered = super().render(name, value, attrs, **kwargs)
        return rendered + mark_safe(u'''
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                   $('#id_%(name)s').chosen({
                        disable_search_threshold: 10,
                   })
                })
            </script>''' % {'name': name})
```

Note there is a call to super, which should refer to `Select`'s and `SelectMultiple`'s render methods respectively.

And then, I define my classes:

```
class ChosenWidgetMultiple(widgets.SelectMultiple, ChosenWidgetParent):
    pass

class ChosenWidget(widgets.Select, ChosenWidgetParent):
    pass
```

This does not work unfortunately, but when I swap the parent classes, it works.

```
class ChosenWidgetMultiple(ChosenWidgetParent, widgets.SelectMultiple):
    pass

class ChosenWidget(ChosenWidgetParent, widgets.Select):
    pass
```

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: I suggest watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo

Comment: Or read [super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: Daniel Roseman: I have seen that article, haven't read it thoroughly but have read some others. This whole method resolution issue seems a little abstract and complicated right now. So, I think a specific input might help. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's the way method resolution works. Python will go through the classes in the order they are declared and call the first method it finds. When you declare the original widget first, Python will find its render method and call it; it will never proceed to your implementation. But when you put yours first, Python will call that, and then when it gets to super() will call the original.

Comment: so super MR work like regular MR but seems like skipping the self object and starting at parents

Comment: I'm not sure of the relevance of that. Your problem didn't have anything to do with `super` at all, but with the original resolution of the `render` method.

Comment: yes, I got it, I was about to note that at the same time you did :) my render never got executed first time

Comment: "when it gets to super()" why would it call the original where mine was the first parent? should not it call my render method again?

Comment: Because `super` literally means "give me the parent". Without an argument it gives you the parent - ie the next in the MRO - of the current class.